# Alexa Rank integration with salesforce

Tags: rest-api, integration, webservices

need to get website rank from alexa and added automatically into salesforce custom objects

https://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/google.com   Rank is 1

custom field

Site__c = Google
Rank__c ==  need to be ( 1)
how can i acheive these functionality ?
Thanks

Comment: Is this REST URI? Did you check what response you are getting in SOAP UI?

Answer (score 0):

There is a free API (though I haven't been able to find any documentation for it anywhere).

http://data.alexa.com/data?cli=10&url=%YOUR_URL%
You can also query for more data the following way:

http://data.alexa.com/data?cli=10&dat=snbamz&url=%YOUR_URL%
All the letters in dat are the ones that determine wich info you get. This dat string is the one I've been able to find wich seems to have more options. Also, cli changes the output completly, this option makes it return an XML with quite a lot of information.

EDIT: This API is the one used by the Alexa toolbar.

Here is example that I did on my browser:

[image]

Now, you can develop apex class/trigger to make callout, get response, parse and store that in Salesforce easily.

Comment: i have tried to use these but we can get max upto 3 only. When ever i created new site need to fetch that information

Comment: Max upto 3 means? You can place a trigger on Site object to get that.

Answer (score 0):

First you need a REST API for this website. Then check what response and in which format you are getting the response from the URI. You can test the response first using SOAP UI. Once you get the response from SOAP UI, you can make a Rest call to that Website. You can refer to below link to make a REST callout from salesforce.

http://blogforce9.blogspot.com/2013/09/salesforce-rest-webservices-part-i.html

Once you get the response from REST API then you can save that data in respective field.